# get null value when return eloquent model relation

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I use eloquent package in project (I do not use laravel!!) when I return a model relation , the result is `null`. But I create relation model !! And in mysql is `true`

In my book model

```php
    public function plandtls()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\plandtls','book_id');
    }
```

and my plandtls

```php
    public function book()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\book','book_id');
    }
```

and execute query :

```php
    public function planList()
    {
        $list = plandtls::select()->with('book')->first();
        var_dump($list);
    }
```

Finaly I get `null` result.

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `select('*')` select all like this

Comment: You can just write `plandtls::with('book')->first()` no need to write select() if you want all columns from plandtls record

Comment: Certainly returns NULL because the request simply doesn't have a result. This is often the problem. Take a good look in your DB to see if the desired content exists.

Comment: @Donkarnash i try it . but i get null again

Comment: @KamleshPaul i try it and get relations:array(0).

Comment: Try `plandtls::with('book')->firstOrFail()` and see what exception and message you are getting

Comment: @Donkarnash ["relations":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["book"]=>
    NULL
  }

Comment: The complete exception - name, message and stacktrace pls

Comment: @Donkarnash i don't get exeption or message